# BigQuery - Implement UTC_USEC_TO_QUARTER

Tags: google-bigquery

I have issued this feature request some time ago (2 months as of now)
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=37&q=label%3DFeature-Request
but didn't get any response. I'd be happy with just "no, we won't do this because..."

I'm doing retention analysis, I can simulate this on my own but it would be convenient to have this as a core function (besides UTC_USEC_TO_DAY, UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK, UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH etc.)

You guys from google BQ team (@Jordan, @Michael, @Fh) are doing great here at stackoverflow but the feature request site seems to be bit "dead" in responding...